# App(with library project) not shown in simulator 

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

jar file of Library project into my app.I make my app dependant to Library.jar by using project properties.The library project contain all code including main class also.I am able to compile both library and Blackberry app  and after compiling, it is generating .cod , .jad files too. I did clean both the project and simulator and compiled but no luck . I tried to compile it from 4.7 to higher versions but no result.
If I move the main class to BB app it is not recognizing the related classes from Library project.
I load the .cod files to simulator manuvally but no result.
When I am compiling the app in console tab it is showing "No entry point found".

Can anybody figure out what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Check the BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml for the checkbox: "Do not display the application icon on the Blackberry home screen" as you might have accidently clicked it.

If that is unchecked, then check if an icon file is being specified in the BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file.

Comment: I checked the checkbox, it is unchecked only..and I am not specify any icon file to Blackberry_App_descriptor.xml..

Comment: Then I suppose the reason it is not showing up in the simulator is because the default icon file got deleted. Check your /res/img folder for a icon.png file. If it is not there, then import a custom icon into the /res folder. Then go into the Blackberry_App_Descriptor.xml file and under "Application Icons"  click Add and then point it to the icon file in the /res folder.